# What is the most time-effective way to monitor & manage threats from bots and/or humans?

Tags: spam-prevention, botattack, protection, 403-forbidden

I'm usually overwhelmed by the amount of tools that hosting companies provide to track & quantify traffic data and statistics.  I'm equally overwhelmed by the countless flavors of malicious 'attacks' that target any and every web site known to man.

The security methods used to protect both the back and front end of a website are documented well and are straight-forward in terms of ease of implementation and application, but the army of autonomous bots knows no boundaries and will always find a niche of a website to infest.

So what can be done to handle the inevitable swarm of bots that pound your domain with brute force?  Whenever I look at error logs for my domains, there are always thousands of entries that look like bots trying to sneak sql code into the database by tricking the variables in the url into giving them schema information or private data within the database.

My barbaric and time-consuming plan of defense is just to monitor visitor statistics for those obvious patterns of abuse and either ban the ips or range of ips accordingly.  Aside from that, I don't know much else I could do to prevent all of the ping pong going on all day.

Are there any good tools that automatically monitor this background activity (specifically activity that throws errors on the web & db server) and proactively deal with these source(s) of mayhem?

Comment: Operating system? Web server? Scripting language/application?

Answer (score 1):

```
Are there any good tools that automatically monitor this background activity (specifically activity that throws errors on the web & db server) and proactively deal with these source(s) of mayhem?
```

"[CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) leverages the knowledge of a diverse community of websites to power a new type of security service. Online threats range from nuisances like comment spam and excessive bot crawling to malicious attacks like SQL injection and denial of service (DOS) attacks. CloudFlare provides security protection against all of these types of threats and more to keep your website safe."

- https://www.cloudflare.com/

Comment: this is pretty cool, thanks.... i now remember seeing a site similar to this in terms of public db of bad ips, but it wasn't interactive and proactive like this one is

Comment: the only thing that i dont like or understand is that you have to change your nameservers.... how does this affect the hosting access?  have you ever personally used this service?

Comment: It doesn't affect hosting access, and they give you a pass-through domain name to use in case of any issue. I've used it for testing.  Seems to do what it says, but I haven't delved too deeply.